# "subprocess.Popen().readline()" in multithreading python cannot return

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, subprocess

For below code running in Win7, there are thread T1 and T2, T1 prints dir content in the original window, and T2 ping for 4 seconds in a new window.

```
import os
import sys
import logging
import subprocess
import threading

class T1 (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        proc = subprocess.Popen("dir", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
            logging.debug(line)
        logging.info("HEREEEEEEEE")

class T2 (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe", "-n", "4", "127.0.0.1"], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
        logging.info("")

if __name__=='__main__':
    logger = logging.getLogger('root')
    FORMAT = "[TID:%(thread)d %(funcName)s L#%(lineno)s] %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.DEBUG)

    t1 = T1()
    t2 = T2()
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

    sys.exit(0)
```

For the line `logging.info("HEREEEEEEEE")` in T1 thread, I think it should be printed right after the content of dir is printed.

What doesn't make sense to me: Why the line isn't printed immediately, but printed 4 seconds later when the thread T2 finished?

I wonder if it's related with file descriptor in multithreading.

Comment: @eryksun It prints dir content correctly, anyway I update my code to avoid confusion.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, dir isn't the key, I think.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you! It works for me. Honestly, I'm not quite clear how close_fds affects the readline(), I will take you tips and study more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 2 your code has a race condition that can leak the inheritable write end of the pipe that's created by the `T1` thread into the ping.exe process that's created by the `T2` thread. `readline` on a pipe won't return until the pipe closes, which requires all handles for the write end to be closed.

In this case, you can avoid the race condition by passing `close_fds=True` to `Popen` when creating the ping.exe process. This prevents it from inheriting inheritable handles, including the pipe handle from the overlapping call in the `T1` thread.

In general, prior to Python 3.7, if you need to support concurrent `Popen` calls with overridden standard handles, then you'll need to wrap `Popen` with a function that synchronizes the call by acquiring a lock beforehand. Unfortunately this makes the `Popen` call a bottleneck in a multi-threaded process, but there's no simple alternative.

---

**Background**

In Unix, the `close_fds` parameter of `Popen` applies in the child process after `fork`. If it's true, then all non-standard file descriptors will be closed before calling `exec`, even those without the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag set. It does not, however, close the standard file descriptors -- stdin (0), stdout (1), and stderr (2).

In Windows, a handle can be flagged as inheritable (i.e. `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT`). By default, handles are not inheritable. If `CreateProcess` is called with `bInheritHandles` as true, then all inheritable handles are inherited by the child. `Popen` passes this as `not close_fds`, i.e. not closing file descriptors means to inherit handles [*].

In Windows, the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` parameters of `Popen` are used to explicitly set the child's standard handles in [`STARTUPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-_startupinfow) (i.e. `hStdInput`, `hStdOutput`, `hStdError`). If the standard handles aren't overridden explicitly, the parent's standard handles are implicitly inherited by console applications (e.g. python.exe), but not GUI applications (e.g. pythonw.exe). If set explicitly, the handles must be made inheritable, and `bInheritHandles` (i.e. `not close_fds`) must be true. This is the source of the race condition when another thread makes an overlapping call to `CreateProcess` that also inherits handles.

In Python 3, the frequency of this race condition is reduced by defaulting `close_fds` to true when the standard handles aren't overridden. In 3.7, it's mitigated further by passing the standard handles in the `lpAttributeList` field of [`STARTUPINFOEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/ns-winbase-_startupinfoexw). With this change, concurrent calls to `Popen` can override the standard handles without leaking handles. However, the handles still have to be made inheritable, so there's still a race condition with concurrent calls to other functions that inherit handles, such as `os.system` and `os.spawnl`.

---

[*] Note that, despite the parameter name, C 'file descriptors' are not actually inherited in Windows. While the C runtime can inherit file descriptors for `system` and the `spawn` / `exec` functions, its use of `STARTUPINFO` to implement this is undocumented. Thus `Popen` only inherits handles. When inheriting a non-standard handle, you need to pass the handle value to the child (e.g. via stdin, the command line, or an environment variable), which you can get via `msvcrt.get_osfhandle`. The child can open a new file descriptor for the inherited handle via `msvcrt.open_osfhandle`.